# AWS Code Deploy failure after converting to an Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-api, aws-code-deploy

I recently converted a private GitHub account to an Organization and that seems to have totally screwed up my authentication with AWS Code Deploy on every one of my repositories.

1. I checked the Webhooks & services for AWS Code Deploy and my keys are set properly.
2. I also re-authenticated with GitHub when creating a new deployment.
3. My AIM permissions have not changed and pass the GitHub Test

But, I receive the following message every time I try to deploy...

```
Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com/repos/artofdev/django/tarball/1ec682b03d3f160d401d0aaf565a66d99f28734e' after 3 retries. Server returned codes: 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'.
```

[EDIT]: I setup a test repo and code deploy application on a personal github account and was able to deploy successfully. Does AWS Code Deploy work with Organization repos?

Comment: Just as a test, can you create a new deployment group and see if there is still an issue? I have see some configuration changes affect existing CD groups, but not new ones.

Comment: I actually had to revert the whole account back to a personal account because this was such a big blocker. All the repos have been migrated over and everything is fixed. I'd like to know what the proper setup is for Organization accounts on GitHub and Code Deploy.

Comment: I never changed the deployment group, it's worth a try.....

Answer (score 2):

There is one more step authorization you need to do if you want to deploy from a private repo controlled by organization.

CodeDeploy just updated with a doc section here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ.html#github-integ-behaviors-org-repositories

Comment: Looks like there is a second authorization step for organizations, I think I'm going to keep it as a user repo since it's half the price though.

Comment: 2nd approval step - https://help.github.com/articles/requesting-organization-approval-for-your-authorized-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Have you retried authenticating CodeDeploy with your new GitHub organization? It is likely that by changing your configuration on GitHub's side your previous authentications were invalidated.

To re-authenticate, you need to create a new deployment from the web console.

You won't need to fully finish creating the deployment, but before you get to the final step, you should see a "Reconnect to GitHub" link.

See [GitHub Authentication with Applications in AWS CodeDeploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ.html#github-integ-behaviors-auth)

Comment: Yes, I tried re-authenticating several times with every repo.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an exactly same issue. Resolution worked for me was:

1. Delete the application
2. Create new application and deployment
3. Re-authenticate with GitHub
4. Authorize codedeploy to access GitHub
5. Deploy

Here without deleting an application, it was not providing a way to re-authorize codedeploy to GitHub and that's the root cause of this issue.

for working your CI integration correctly, Go to -- You profile -->setting --> Application --> Authorize OAuth app should list codedeploy.